# Multiple, sequential tasks in one workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

I have a couple steps in a declarative workflow that each collect data from users. I need each collection task to be completed before the next step kicks off. Is this possible. Also, the workflow is started by the user in this instance, not by item created or changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have workflows call other workflows in SP Designer. You can have it so that a user can fire a workflow, and those workflows call other workflows when a task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Please read the following article:

[Creating Multiple Tasks from a SharePoint 2010 Workflow Sequentially](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx)

Comment: So there doesn't seem to be a way to do it in SPD? I was going to have a "completion" check column in the list for each step and have the other steps check the value before running, but then I would have to enable the item changed event on the list